# Add text parameters in angular ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I am trying to add parameters to ui-sref. If I try this it works perfectly

```
<a ui-sref="services.test({ id: 2 , other_id: 3 })">test</a>
```

But If I try this it don't work

```
<a ui-sref="services.test({ id: firstexmple , other_id: secondone })">test</a>
```

Comment: Are `firstexmple` and `secondone` variable names? Or are they intended as literal values "firstexmple" and "secondone"?

Comment: literal values, but it don't works wit ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to set the `id` to literal value "firstexample" and `other_id` to "secondone" you need to write them as you would write strings in plain JavaScript code, so:

```
<a ui-sref="services.test({ id: 'firstexmple' , other_id: 'secondone' })">test</a>
```

(mind that you can't use double quotes (like this `id: "firstexmple"`) because you're already using them as to wrap the whole `ui-sref` attribute's value.